# Authentication of user

Tags: authentication, bcrypt, bcryptjs

I am trying to check my password in while logging in in I also have hashed my password. so I am comparing it using brcrypt. But it is giving me error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAE8f.png) my user schema is this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmiC8.png)  and my login functoin is this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwBdu.png)

Comment: You should enter error messages and code as text not screenshots so others can copy them and to make your entry searchable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }).lean().exec();
```

should be

```
let user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
```

Because `lean` has result is `plain old JavaScript objects (POJOs), not Mongoose documents.` [Ref to here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html)

Comment: Truly Great Thank you @nartoan